# LeakCanary is not able to find the paths to retained ojects

Tags: android, leakcanary

While searching for memory leaks in an app using LeakCanary, I stumbled upon a a strange result:

[image]

This is the interesting part of the Logcat:

```
D/LeakCanary: Found 9 objects retained, dumping heap now (app is visible & >=5 threshold)
D/LeakCanary: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission not granted, ignoring
D/LeakCanary: Setting up flushing for Thread[LOCATION,5,main]
D/LeakCanary: Analysis in progress, working on: PARSING_HEAP_DUMP
D/LeakCanary: Analysis in progress, working on: EXTRACTING_METADATA
D/LeakCanary: Analysis in progress, working on: FINDING_RETAINED_OBJECTS
D/LeakCanary: Setting up flushing for Thread[IntentService[HeapAnalyzerService],5,main]
D/LeakCanary: Analysis in progress, working on: FINDING_PATHS_TO_RETAINED_OBJECTS
D/LeakCanary: Found 25 retained objects
D/LeakCanary: Found 0 paths to retained objects
D/LeakCanary: Analysis in progress, working on: INSPECTING_OBJECTS
D/LeakCanary: Analysis in progress, working on: COMPUTING_NATIVE_RETAINED_SIZE
D/LeakCanary: Analysis in progress, working on: COMPUTING_RETAINED_SIZE
D/LeakCanary: Analysis in progress, working on: BUILDING_LEAK_TRACES
D/LeakCanary: Analysis in progress, working on: REPORTING_HEAP_ANALYSIS
D/LeakCanary: ​
    ====================================
    HEAP ANALYSIS RESULT
    ====================================
    0 APPLICATION LEAKS
    
    References underlined with "~~~" are likely causes.
    Learn more at https://squ.re/leaks.
    ====================================
    0 LIBRARY LEAKS
    
    A Library Leak is a leak caused by a known bug in 3rd party code that you do not have control over.
    See https://square.github.io/leakcanary/fundamentals-how-leakcanary-works/#4-categorizing-leaks
    ====================================
    METADATA
    
    Please include this in bug reports and Stack Overflow questions.
    
    Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 29
    Build.MANUFACTURER: samsung
    LeakCanary version: 2.5
    App process name: 
    Stats: LruCache[maxSize=3000,hits=7157,misses=65789,hitRate=9%]
    RandomAccess[bytes=3638897,reads=65789,travel=66202063325,range=23021778,size=54136938]
    Analysis duration: 17316 ms
    Heap dump file path: 
    Heap dump timestamp: 1605711733381
    Heap dump duration: 1506 ms
    ====================================
```

It seems that leakcanary can't get the paths, which is strange...
Is there an other way to see the retained objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LeakCanary navigates the object graph, starting from all GC roots (e.g. static fields) and following references. This result means LeakCanary did not find a path that lead to the leaking instances.

LeakCanary only follows strong references and ignores weak references, as those should not prevent objects from being garbage collected. You can see the list of ignored references here: https://github.com/square/leakcanary/blob/main/shark-android/src/main/java/shark/AndroidReferenceMatchers.kt#L1159-L1236

One thing you could do is customize that list, removing some entries. Keep in mind that LeakCanary only gives you the shortest path, so there might be several paths that go through an ignored reference.

Otherwise you can use Eclipse MAT (free) or YourKit (best tool but not free): https://square.github.io/leakcanary/faq/#how-can-i-dig-beyond-the-leak-trace

Another option is to pull the heap dump, then write a small Kotlin script that runs the analysis and tweak the configuration until you find what you're looking for: https://square.github.io/leakcanary/shark/#generating-a-heap-analysis-report

Comment: I have the same situation (8 objects retained but no paths shown), and was able to find using the Android Profiler that my activity and viewmodel were not being GCed, but where do I go from here? If there are no strong references to my activity, what could be preventing it from being GCed?